# Docker: Error response from daemon: remove myvol: volume is in use

Tags: docker

When I'm trying to remove a volume I get this error:

> Error response from daemon: remove myvol: volume is in use -
> [2a177cb40a405db9f245fccd776dcdeacc d266ad624daf7cff510c9a1a1716fe]

But both `docker ps` and `docker container ls` return an empty list.

I've tried restarting the docker daemon.

I use Docker Toolbox on Windows 10.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

try to delete all stopped containers:

```
docker rm -f $(docker ps -a -q)
```

then delete the volume

you can see stopped container using `docker ps -a` using `docker ps` will return only running containers

**EDIT since you are on Windows**

list stopped containers:

```
docker ps -a
```

delete the stopped container - you need to replace CONTAINER_ID with your real ones -:

```
docker rm -f CONTAINER_ID_1 CONTAINER_ID_2
```

Comment: "docker rm -f $(dcoker ps -a -q)" throws "unknown shorthand flag: 'a' in -a"

Comment: are you on windows ?

Comment: Yes, I am on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this error, you need to remove the container [2a177cb40a405db9f245fccd776dcdeacc d266ad624daf7cff510c9a1a1716fe] before removing the volume.

You can use this ID to remove the container:

`$ docker rm 2a177cb40a405db9f245fccd776dcdeacc d266ad624daf7cff510c9a1a1716fe`

Note: Removing the container will not affect the volume. The ls command will still list this volume.

`$ docker volume ls`

After you removed the container, the volume is now free for deletion. so you can use the rm command to delete the Docker volume “[Volume Name]”:

`$ docker volume rm [Volume Name]`